# Grub Loader doesnt appear

Tags: linux, windows, grub, kali-linux

I have Windows 8 in my Samsung laptop. I wanted to install kali-linux, so I downloaded the image and burned it into a DVD. When I installed it kali-linux told me to remove the DVD and it completed the installation.

It rebooted but there was not GRUB when I rebooted kali, instead it booted into Windows 8 directly.

I tried booting from a live CD and gparted but that did not solve it.

**How can I show GRUB at boot to boot into Kali?**

Comment: In `Disk Management` in Windows, do you see Kali's partitions? (there should be 2 "unknown" partitions in addition to Windows')

Comment: Yes i can see one of 28.74 gb, i supose is the principal, one of 1.26 gb, and another of 1 mb.